# Where is my "global inbox"?

Tags: discussion, email

I received an e-mail beginning "The following items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last checked it on 2015-01-30:"  But I've been looking at answers to my questions every day for the past two weeks.  Is there something called a "global inbox"?  And if so, where do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "global inbox" is the name of the inbox next to the Stack Exchange logo.  This is available on all Stack Exchange sites, hence global.

[image]